# REGEX to find only street number for PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a spider to filter contact information by type, and I've run across a regular expression that seems to have a great deal of promise. The only issue is that it requires the entire mailing address in order to pass scrutiny.

```
^(?n:(?<address1>(\d{1,5}(\ 1\/[234])?(\x20[A-Z]([a-z])+)+ )|(P\.O\.\ 
Box\ \d{1,5}))\s{1,2}(?i:(?<address2>(((APT|B LDG|DEPT|FL|HNGR|LOT|PIER|RM|S
(LIP|PC|T(E|OP))|TRLR|UNIT)\x20\w{1,5})|(BSMT|FRNT|LBBY|LOWR|OFC|PH|REAR|SIDE|UPPR)\.?)
\s{1,2})?)(?<city>[A-Z]([a-z])+(\.?)(\x20[A-Z]([a-z])+){0,2})\, 
\x20(?<state>A[LKSZRAP]|C[AOT]|D[EC]|F[LM]|G[AU]|HI|I[ADL N]|K[SY]|LA|M
[ADEHINOPST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[ARW]|RI|S[CD] |T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY])
\x20(?<zipcode>(?!0{5})\d{5}(-\d {4})?))$
```

I need the expression to only require the street number and name. I don't understand how each piece of the expression is broken-up, however. Otherwise, I'd make the changes on my own. **How would I alter the expression to accept any mailing address with up to 4 digits on the street number followed by any type of words (since there isn't a strong validation system when the addresses are input)?**

---

### Currently Accepted Inputs:

```
123 Park Ave Apt 123 New York City, NY 10002 
P.O. Box 12345 Los Angeles, CA 12304
```

### Currently Denied Inputs:

```
123 Main St 
123 City, State 00000
123 street city, ST 00000
```

### Desired Accepted Inputs:

```
123 Park Ave Apt 123 
P.O. Box 12345 
9784 Hwy 12
92 Main St
972 Smith dr
```

### Desired Denied Inputs:

```
123 Main St, New York NY 14676
123 City, State 00000
123 street city, ST 00000
12345 street
```

Comment: @Braj, sorry about that. I got a little question happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a good start

```
/^(\d{1,4}|P\.O\.)([a-zA-Z\s]+)(\d+)?$/i    
/^(\d{1,4}|P\.O\.)\s([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)\s?(\d+)?$/i
/^(\d{1,4}\s|P\.O\.)([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)(\d+)?$/i

// passes
123 Park Ave Apt 123
P.O. Box 12345
9784 Hwy 12
92 Main St
972 Smith dr
1809 Caddo St
10200 Highway 5 North

// fails 
123 Main St, New York NY 14676
123 City, State 00000
123 street city, ST 00000
12345 street
```

Usage:

```
<?php

$address = "123 Park Ave Apt 123";
$pattern = '/^(\d{1,4}|P\.O\.)([a-zA-Z\s]+)(\d+)?$/i';
if(preg_match($pattern, $address, $matches)){
    echo $matches[0];
}

?>
```

Testing in progress... :)

[RegEx Fiddle](http://regex101.com/r/fZ5vL6/1)

Comment: My mistake. That was passing. The test I set up had the "PASSED" and "FAILED" alerts switched. Strings that fail are as follows: "1020 West 4th Street, Suite 400", "701 North 9th Street", "2101 Hwy 367 N", "127 W 4th St" and "700 N 2nd St".

Comment: Would I update the `([a-zA-Z\s]+)` statement to read something like `(([a-zA-Z\s]+)|(\d[a-z\s]+))` ?

Comment: The code snippet I just added doesn't actually work. :\

Comment: (\d[a-z\s]+) => match one digit, match one ore more characters and spaces. It's fine if you think it would be needed :) Could you provide an example of this

Comment: @elersong The snippet above has been tested on my server before pasting here.

Comment: @elersong You should't add `\d[a-z\s]+` to the expression 'cause the following address `12345 street` will pass. Let it this way if it does the job :)

Comment: I'm running into issues trying to get the addresses like those above to pass. "10200 Highway 5 North" and so on. Any ideas?

Comment: @elersong But this address `10200 Highway 5 North` starts with 5 digits :) Haven't we said 4 :) Anyhow, it will pass but... you should check if is there any other exception

Comment: Array ( [0] => 10200 Highway 5 North [1] => 917 Highway 64 E [2] => 701 North 9th Street [3] => 2101 Hwy 367 N [4] => 127 W 4th St [5] => Central Blvd [6] => 700 N 2nd St [7] => Hwy 56 [8] => 32117 Hwy 22 P.O. Box 192 [9] => 305 S 5th St [10] => Hwy 65 S [11] => 105 W 3rd St)

Comment: You're right. I do want to skip all addresses with 5 digits because I'm using that as my regex to recognize zip codes. But those are all the street numbers that didn't pass the first test. The biggest issue is getting the snippet to recognize numbers within the string and numbers that start street names. I can't seem to be able to update the regex to recognize those.

Comment: @elersong I'm not quite familiar with these addresses but if you tell me what should pass and what shouldn't :) I could try to build a new or modify the expression above.

Comment: I think this snippet is working, `/^(\d{1,4}\s|P\.O\.)([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)(\d+)?$/i`, but honestly it may be another function in the program that's recognizing the pattern. Regardless, I couldn't have made it this far without your help.

Comment: @elersong I'm glad I could help. I added all three version to the answer and if you find any other exception feel free to drop me a note :)